# If $||f-g_n|| \to \inf_{g\in S} ||f-g||$ and $||g_n-g_0||\to 0 ,$then $ \inf_{g\in S}||f-g||=||f-g_0||$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $||f-g_n|| \to \inf_{g\in S} ||f-g||$ and $||g_n-g_0||\to 0 ,$then $ \inf_{g\in S}||f-g||=||f-g_0||$

Note: S is a closed subspace of Hilbert Space S.

I am just wondering how to show $||f-g_0||$ is actually the infimum? Does the following work? By the triangle inequality, $||f-g_0||\leq ||f-g_n||+||g_n-g_0||$
and taking limit as $n\to \infty$ we get $||f-g_o||\leq \inf_{g\in S}||f-g||$. But since $g_0$ is in S (as S closed), then the only way for that inequality to hold is if $||f-g_o||=\inf_{g\in s}||f-g||$ ? Is my argument correct? How to make it more precise with epsilons? Thanks.

edit: I guess an even more general result follows, using continuity of the norm..

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct.

The only step that needs more rigour is showing that $||f-g_0|| \leq ||f - g_n|| + ||g_n-g_0||$ implies $||f-g_0||\leq \inf_{g\in S}||f-g||$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be s.t. $\min(||f-g_n||-\inf_{g\in S}||f-g||, \ ||g_n-g_0||) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then substitute into the first equation to get $||f-g_0||\leq \inf_{g\in S}||f-g|| + \epsilon$.

Comment: ah I see thanks but I just thought since I have found an element in the set that is less than or equal to the infimum of the set then by definition of infimum it can only be equal to it.